# Django - Remove HTTPS redirect

Tags: django, ssl, https, pythonanywhere

I've a django app hosted on pythonanywhere servers.
Some days ago, while editing this website, I've added in the settings.py file some variables about the https and ssl connection.

Obviously I didn't want the https while I don't have the certificate, but I forgot those variable in the settings file.

After the upload of files, going on the site, I saw that I've forgot those variables.
I've immediatly deleted the variables from the settings file and re uploaded, but the problem persists.
I mean, if I go to the site there is a redirect to https that I don't want.
The outcome is "Connection is not private" whit a red barred https.

Could you please tell me how to fix this problem? how to remove the automatic redirect to https and aboid the message "connection is not private" ?

Thank you in advance!!!

edit:

I know that if I go to http://siteaddress everything is ok. but if in the address bar you put just www.siteaddres.com it's automatically redirect to https://www.siteaddress.com

Comment: This is likely a caching problem. Try clearing your cache or incognito.

Comment: nope... already done. And also accessing to the site from dirrent devices I get the same problem

Answer (score 7):

It was a caching problem.
I'm using google chrome and when you go to Clear browsing data you have to set all and not just the last hour or what it's set

Comment: Actually worked for me with "the last hour" as I did the wrong change and reverted within an hour

Comment: Thanks! I should use incognito mode more often to avoid this situation :)